# train schedules for freight trains?

Tags: usa

I've taken an interest to filming trains as they go over bridges. For commuter trains I can guestimate when they'll be over a bridge based on the times that they're going to be at the stop before the bridge and the stop after the bridge. But not all train routes have commuter trains - some just run freight trains and that's it. For these freight trains...  is there a way I could look up scheduled stops online? If I knew what time they were going to be at the stop before and the stop after I could camp out at a bridge for that length of time (possibly guestimating the time that they'll cross the bridge) and take the picture I want to take.

The alternative is just to camp out for a potentially indefinite period of time, which has little appeal to me. If I'm going to be camping out I'd prefer to know how long I'd need to be there to get the shot I want to get.